# How to Change Desktop on windows OS

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, graphics, desktop

I'm tired of using static pictures as my desktop.
so I 'm tring to make a  dynamic desktop by coding.
I'm not making a video.
My plan was to make the program draw pictures and update these pictures to the desktop.
But it failed.After run the code the desktop didn't change at all.
My code is as follow.

[output of my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjTi3.png)

Here is the func supposed to update the desktop.
SwitchDesktop(CreateDesktop("NumRain",NULL,NULL,DF_ALLOWOTHERACCOUNTHOOK,DESKTOP_CREATEWINDOW,NULL));

[My code at codepad](http://codepad.org/So65wSs5)

P.S.My OS is Win 7.

Comment: If you're trying to do a video: VLC can show a movie as your desktop background. There's also some COM interface you can use, as well as a built in UI feature to make it a webpage with the video. There's also Dreamscene.

Comment: Which version of windows are you using?  And please post the relevant portion of your code inline - do not link to an external site.

Comment: How does it fail? What behavior were you expecting and what behavior did you get? Please put that information in your question

Comment: I've edit the question.Sorry for not declaring it clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Win32 API you want to use is [`SystemParametersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the action `SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER`. See [example three of this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/97142) for a Visual Basic example you should be able to adapt.